# Why do we use plural when we say "blow someone's brains out"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

My simplistic thinking is that each person has one brain, so why do we say "blow someone's brains out"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's hard to say, since we've been doing it as long as the word has been around. The OED gives: 
 I. Senses denoting organic structures.
 1. a. The organ contained in the skull of humans and other vertebrates
b. In pl. in the same senses.
Now usu. as a mass noun, chiefly in Cookery.

?c1400    tr. Secreta Secret. (Sloane) 11   *Many heres and softe signyfies buxomnes and coldnes of brains.*

As for the comment about mass noun, note that you don't blow the entire brain out, just bits of it.

Comment: My electronic edition of the OED adds: *In 16th c. it became usual to employ the pl. instead of the sing. when mere cerebral substance, and not a definite organic structure, was meant; this usage still continues: we say ‘a dish of brains’, ‘a disease of the brain’.*

Comment: @Laure, and that's presumably where [etymonline](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/53320/3461) (which is, after all, a compiler) got it from.

Comment: And also _'sliced brain, diced brain, pureed brain, grilled brain'_. The first two imply some larger structure to dissect, the third is the usual massification, and the last one is indeed a whole brain (or integral portion thereof). Massification is the semantic effect of using a count noun in a situation that clearly calls for a mass noun. The classic example is _After the explosion, there was scientist all over the lab,_ where _scientist_ clearly refers to the same kind of structural integrity as _brains_ that get blown out.

Answer (score 6):

I see nothing at all wrong with @Brett Reynolds's excellent answer - I'm only really posting this to graphically illustrate that plural *brains* has always been as common as *brain*, [even for one individual.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=use%20his%20brains,use%20his%20brain&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

[image]

Maybe it's because if you actually look at a brain, it seems to be made of lots of bits (we certainly do the same with *guts*). Or maybe we think we're so smart the singular doesn't do justice to the organ.

Comment: But [*his brain* beats *his brains*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+brains%2Chis+brain&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) by 4x.  *Brains* has a different connotation than *brain*, and is more common in certain contexts than *brain* (i.e. [*blow his brains out*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blow+his+brain+out%2Cblow+his+brains+out&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), [*use his brains*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blow+his+brain+out%2Cblow+his+brains+out&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), etc.)

Comment: @Daniel: You got the last link *(use his brains)* wrong there (it should match *even for one individual* in my answer). Obviously for *his brain* to outrank *his brains* by 4:1 there must be lots of usages that *do* favour it, but *use* (also *racked* and the execrable *wracked*) all come out about equal. Curiously, *taxed* is almost always with singular, so I think it's not just a matter of semantics (there's no obvious reason why that particular kind of use should be different to the others). If I find a context that clearly favours the plural, I'll add examples of each to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Beats me, but [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=brain) notes:

> The custom of using the plural to refer to the substance (literal or figurative), as opposed to the organ, dates from [the sixteenth century].

Comment: +1 Because I think it’s really as simple as this. One brain, a splatter of brains.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't "blow someone's brain out" unless you are Bond.

*Brain* is physiology. *Brains* is a metaphor. In fact, *brains* here is a not a plural in the usual sense, but merely signifies that it is a metaphor. It's so with several other words as well.