# Origin of "blew his brains out"

Tags: etymology, expressions, idioms

I was thinking to myself, when suddenly a thought occurred to me: When was the first usage of "blew his brains out"?

Example as used in sentence:

> He put the shotgun in his mouth with one shell in the chamber. He pulled the trigger and blew his brains out.

Just my curiosity getting the better of me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53319/why-do-we-use-plural-when-we-say-blow-someones-brains-out

Comment: You may find the following list useful: http://www.idiomconnection.com/head.html

Comment: The **origin** was clearly the inside of his head. The target was the wall behind him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earliest instance of "blow out [one's] brains" in a Google Books search of various possessive forms used to refer to the actual or prospective victim's brains is from [*Calendar of State Papers, Colonial Series*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sKsMAQAAIAAJ&q=%22threatning+to+blow+out+his+brains%22&dq=%22threatning+to+blow+out+his+brains%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gZFRVdSRFYPysAXPioDoCA&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1723) [combined snippets]:

> Deposition of Habbijah Savage, of Bermudas, Mariner. Antigua, Feb. 13, 1723. Bound from St. Eustatia to Grantire in the sloop *Postillion*, he was on 2nd Jan. last past taken by a sloop called the *Postillion* commanded by M. D' Buke, appointed guard d'coast to the French Islands. D' Buke striped him and his crew of all their apparel except what they then wore. D' Buke carried this deponent with his sloop into Martinique and in his passage thither the Lieut. of said sloop asked deponent for the money he had brought to purchase his cargo to which this Deponent answered that he had none for that purpose. The Lieut. ordered four lighted matches to be put between deponent's fingers and stood by him with his pistol cocked to his breast, threatning to **blow out his brains**. After some time, one of the men belonging to the French sloop told the Lt. that the barbarity he used was more than he could answer etc.

Another early instance appears in Laurence Clarke, [*Exposition on the Common Prayer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FNdbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT99&dq=%22blow+out+his+brains%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=p5RRVaLPBMKayASg3oDQDg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBDgU#v=onepage&q=%22blow%20out%20his%20brains%22&f=false) (January 4, 1737):

> The same Day, about Four o'Clock in the Afternoon, one Thomas Lawrence, Servant to Mr. Palmer, a Carpenter in Friday street, was attack'd in Stepney Fields by a Footpad dress'd in a Sailor's Habit, who held a Pistol to him, and swore he would **blow out his Brains**, if he did not deliver his Money ; but he snatch'd the Pistol out of the Rogue's Hand and threw it into a Ditch ; after which he scuffled with him, till two Gentlemen came to his Assistance, in whose hands he left him and ran away.

And from "[The Political State in September 1738](https://books.google.com/books?id=I39YAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA237&dq=%22blow+out+their+brains%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pI5RVZ6uHJKxyAT-o4DACA&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22blow%20out%20their%20brains%22&f=false)," in *The Political State of Great Britain*, volume 56 (1738):

> The Rogue ["a single Footpad"] behaved in a most insolent Manner to the Passengers, threatning every Minute to **blow out their Brains** with a Horse-pistol, which he held in his Hand ; there was another Villain that stood at a small Distance from him, to cover and protect his Villainy ; and tho' he had got so good a Sum from the Company [aboard "the flying Bath Coach"], he cursed them in a terrible Manner, because they produced no better a Booty, and said Gentlemen were not obliged to be at the Expence of Powder and Ball, and likewise a long Attendance on the Road, to loose their Time for so slender a Profit.

These results indicate that people have been threatening to blow out one another's brains since soon after firearms became a practical alternative to swords, daggers, axes, and pikes in the arsenals of military men and private citizens.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to construct the same phrase and *OED* lists the phrase as *to blow a person's (also one's) brains out*. Surprisingly, in the earliest example from *OED*, the phrase is constructed as *to blow out the brains of someone.*

The earliest citation given in *OED* is from 1743:

> Our Hero next applied himself to another of his Gang, who instantly received his Orders, and instead of hesitating at a single Murther, asked if he should **blow out the Brains of all the Passengers, Coachman and all**.
>
> <sub>H. Fielding *Jonathan Wild* iii. iv, in *Misc.* III. 210</sub>

You can also see the original version here in Google Books:
 [*Miscellanies, Volume 2
By Henry Fielding*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=HykJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA210&dq=%22+blow+out+the+Brains+of+all+the+Passengers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Om1RVfbxEsGayASb2oCICQ&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBzgy#v=onepage&q=%22%20blow%20out%20the%20Brains%20of%20all%20the%20Passengers%22&f=false)